# Matrix space, with $\langle A,B\rangle=\text{tr}(AB^*)$ isn't Hilbert space, how can i find a counter example?

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-sequences

Generally, I'm having quite troubles thinking about counter examples.
So I would love if someone could guide me into finding the example for the following question by myself (and not just giving it away).

Let $$M=\{A=(a_{i,j})_{i,j\in N} | a_{i,j}\in \Bbb C, a_{i,j} \not=0 \text{ for only finitely many } i,j\}$$

[Please note that the matrices are infinite].

Define $\langle A,B\rangle =\text{tr}(AB^*)$.

I have managed to prove that this is indeed an inner product.

Now i'm trying to show that it is not a Hilbert space, by finding a cauchy's sequence that does not converge.

My "intuition" was to find a sequence of matrix such as in every matrix there would be only finite number of index' in which the value isn't 0, but it would have to "converge" to a matrix with infinte number of such index'.

I was trying to do it using matrix that would get values $1+1/n$, so it won't go to zero, and yet will somehow behave like a Cauchy sequence.

My two main idea (which were wrong) is $M_n =1+ 1/n$ on the diagonal until the $n$th place.

Any guidelines would be blessed.
Thanks

Comment: But this is finite dimensional, so it must be complete.

Comment: @John
Why is that finite dimentional? It is infinite matrix (NxN)

Comment: You are trying to show that the space $M$ is not complete, right?

Comment: @Tom
Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $A_n$ is the $\Bbb{N} \times \Bbb{N}$ matrix $A_n = \operatorname{diag}\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, ..., \frac{1}{2^{n}}, 0, 0, ...\}$, then you can show that $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a  Cauchy sequence in $M$, but that it doesn't have a limit in $M$.

In fact, if you choose any sequence in $\ell_2(\Bbb{R})$ and build your matrices with the partial sequence along the diagonal in the same way as above, you'll be able to show the resulting sequence of matrices doesn't converge in $M$.

Comment: That was very helpfull, especially the clerification with $l_2(C)$. Thanks